# The Quintessential Quintuplets (aka 五等分の花嫁) : Is 届くんです (it reaches) a mondegreen that should be 五等分です (It's divided into five equal parts)?

Tags: translation, nuances, song-lyrics, music, song

In [animesonglyrics](https://www.animesonglyrics.com/gotoubun-no-hanayome/gotoubun-no-kimochi), you can see in the season 1 opening (Gotoubun no Kimochi) for the anime adaptation of [The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quintessential_Quintuplets)

1. the Romaji: Go-tōbundesu, demo (...) --> the Kanji of which I think is: 五等分です, でも (...)
2. the English: It reaches, but (...)
3. the Kanji: 届くんです, でも (...) --> the Romaji of which I think is: Todokundesu, demo (...)

source: https://www.animesonglyrics.com/gotoubun-no-hanayome/gotoubun-no-kimochi

[image]

It seems the English and the Kanji match, but they are both different from the romaji.

Now, in a live performance [here](https://youtu.be/_g7geUDY1ts?t=69), you can see the actress/singer Inori Minase holds up 5 fingers when singing this line, sooo...

[image]

1. I guess the Romaji is correct, while the English and Kanji are wrong?
2. But it's a mondegreen, i.e. it's understandable to mishear Go-tōbun (五等分) as 届く (Todoku)?

Comment: Cross-posted to Anime.SE: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/66495/2516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different sources list it as 五等分. For example search up 五等分の気持ち 歌詞. Like this one https://utaten.com/lyric/mi19011506/. Many sources says it's 五等分. The lyrics on animesonglyrics I think might be wrong here, maybe the contributors of the site misheard it. Then someone who translated from the Japanese also translated it as "It reaches" to english.

But nonetheless, weird how the romaji keeps it as 五等分.

As for how one can mishear 五等分です as 届くんです, I can't say. Hopefully someone else can answer that.

Comment: Thanks firuvi. Do you agree with andrew's answer here? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/the-quintessential-quintuplets-aka-%e4%ba%94%e7%ad%89%e5%88%86%e3%81%ae%e8%8a%b1%e5%ab%81-is-%e5%b1%8a%e3%81%8f%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-it-reaches-a-mondegreen/66497#66497

Comment: @BCLC Yep, I also believe it was just a mistake and not likely mishearing the lyrics.